# How to implement an ORM in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, orm

I am trying to implement my own ORM in C# for MySQL as the one I have found are not able to do exactly what I want.

I currently have implemented only a few methods (eg save method):

```
public void Save()
    {
        string queryVariables = "";
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name != "BdClass" && x.GetValue(this) != null))
        {
            string isLast = this.GetType().GetProperties().Last() == propertyInfo ? "" : ", ";
            queryVariables += $"{propertyInfo.Name} = '{MySqlHelper.EscapeString(propertyInfo.GetValue(this).ToString())}'{isLast}";
        }
        ConnectionSingleton.Query($"INSERT INTO {this.GetType().GetProperties().Single(x => x.Name == "BdClass").GetValue(this)} SET {queryVariables} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {queryVariables};");
    }
```

I am trying to implement the FindAll() method which I want it to return me a List with the type of the object calling the function. Let's say I have a class called Person and I want to get all the rows of the Person table from the database, I want to write it this way:

```
List<Person> persons = Person.FindAll();
```

I am struggling with the creation of the object in the FindAll() method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the shortcomings of existing ORM's that you feel you need to write your own? I'm sure there is a way to bend existing (tested) ORM libraries to include the functionality you want through extensions rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I haven't found any open source MySQL ORM that can return me a List of object of the type I want. If you know one which does this (or something close) I would love to hear about it!

Comment: Entity Framework can do it: [here is a forum post on how to set it up](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264). Then you just use the appropriate Linq query against the Dbset and then you can call `.ToList` if you want a list from the query results.

Comment: Dapper may help you. Very fast and lightweight ORM. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Rainbow.MySql/

Comment: Dapper .net might also be able to do what you're looking for if you don't want all of the overhead associated with EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Insight Db](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database). We are using it to handle Sql Server, Oracle and DB2. It supports MySQL also. I find it really easy to use and saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [NEntityDb](https://nentitydb.com). It supports MySQL and other databases such as SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, IBM Db2 MariaDB, Sqlite or Firebird.

With [NEntityDb for MySQL](https://nentitydb.com/pages/docs/database-providers/mysql,-mariadb-and-percona-server.html) you can query and save data to the database with .NET LINQ Expressions and Fluent API.